# Matching binary data using boost regex

Tags: c++, boost-regex

**Is boost regex able to match binary data in a given binary input?**

Ex.:
Input in binary form:
`0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x08`

Binary expression to match:
`0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04`

In this case, 2 instances should be matched.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, boost::regex supports binary.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [answer]

Answer (score 0):

> Your question is not clean enough to me. So If this answer **is not** what
>   you looking for, just tell me I will **delete** it.

The `regex` boost library is much powerful than `C++` as you can in the screenshot:

[image]

[picture source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Also when the **C++** can do it, of course **Boost** can do it, as well.
`std::regex::iterator`

```
std::string binary( "0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x08" );
std::basic_regex< char > regex( "0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04" );
// or
// std::basic_regex< char > regex( "0x01.+?4" );
std::regex_iterator< std::string::iterator > last;
std::regex_iterator< std::string::iterator > begin( binary.begin(), binary.end(), regex );

while( begin != last ){
    std::cout << begin->str() << '\n';
    ++begin;
}
```

**output**

```
0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04
0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04
```

**or**
`std::regex_token::iterator`

```
std::string binary( "0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x08" );
std::basic_regex< char > regex( " 0x0[58] ?" );
std::regex_token_iterator< std::string::iterator > last;
std::regex_token_iterator< std::string::iterator > begin( binary.begin(), binary.end(), regex, -1 );

while( begin != last ){
    std::cout << *begin << '\n';
    ++begin;
}
```

**output**
as the same

---

**With boost**

```
std::string binary( "0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x08" );
boost::basic_regex< char > regex( " 0x0[58] ?" );

boost::regex_token_iterator< std::string::const_iterator > last;
boost::regex_token_iterator< std::string::const_iterator > begin( binary.begin(), binary.end(), regex, -1 );

while( begin != last ){
    std::cout << *begin << '\n';
    ++begin;
}
```

**output**
as the same

> difference:  **std::string::const_iterator**, instead of **std::string::iterator**